# Oracle SOA call from Java using Ant

Tags: java, ant, soa

I have a usecase to deploy a Oracle SOA composite from Java. For this I am using Apache ANT API to call ant-sca-package.xml ant file from my java code.

```
    File buildFile = new File("/xyz/fmwhome/AS11gR1SOA/bin/ant-sca-compile.xml");
    Project p = new Project();        
    p.setUserProperty("ant.file", buildFile.getAbsolutePath());             

    DefaultLogger consoleLogger = new DefaultLogger();
    consoleLogger.setErrorPrintStream(System.err);
    consoleLogger.setOutputPrintStream(System.out);
    consoleLogger.setMessageOutputLevel(Project.MSG_INFO);
    p.addBuildListener(consoleLogger);

    try {
            p.fireBuildStarted();
            p.init();
            ProjectHelper helper = ProjectHelper.getProjectHelper();
            p.addReference("ant.projectHelper", helper);
            helper.parse(p, buildFile);
            p.setProperty("scac.input", "/xyz/Sample/Sample/composite.xml");            
            p.executeTarget(p.getDefaultTarget()); 
            p.fireBuildFinished(null);
    } catch (BuildException e) {
            p.fireBuildFinished(e);
    }
```

I am seeing the following error.

> /xyz/fmwhome/AS11gR1SOA/bin/ant-sca-compile.xml:201:
>   /xyz/fmwhome/AS11gR1SOA/bin/${env.JAVA_HOME}/lib not found.

Do I need to add all jars needed for ant file to classpath from my code? I have already added them to libraries and classpath section of my project in jdeveloper.

Not sure what I am missing. Please provide your inputs.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Probably your java home isn't set; can you print the class path from ant and show us your $PATH and $JAVA_HOME environment variables.

Comment: <echo message="java home: ${env.JAVA_HOME}"/>
<echo message="path: ${env.CLASSPATH}"/> messages print java home: ${env.JAVA_HOME} path: ${env.CLASSPATH}, can I set these parameters from my code?

Comment: What is the result if you execute that code?